# uitableview drag down outside screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview, parallax, contentoffset

I'm basically trying to achieve this effect: http://youtu.be/VBW2i0P11iI

The tableview is a basic one that's pinned to it's superview with autolayout. The view underneath is added with the classic insertSubview:belowSubview: / addChildViewController combo.

I've tried a couple of approaches. What I have now is:

```html
if (scrollOffset >= -scrollView.contentInset.top) {
        self.resultsTableViewContainerTopConstraint.constant = 0;
    } else {
        self.resultsTableViewContainerTopConstraint.constant = MAX(self.resultsTableViewContainerTopConstraint.constant, self.resultsTableViewContainerTopConstraint.constant - scrollDiff);
    }
}
```

So I'm basically changing the top constraint based on the delta of contentOffset. The problem with this is that the uitableview bounces back so it always gets into the first branch of the if. But even if I solve this problem I feel like I'll just patch it. I'm sure there's a way more elegant way of achieving the effect in the video having the same responsiveness.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but I hacked up a quick demo:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *headerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblTitle;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnReset;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewTopConstraint;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)initViews
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.headerView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.headerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
    self.headerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    self.headerView.layer.shadowRadius = 4;

    self.lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.lblTitle.text = @"HEADER VIEW";
    self.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    self.btnReset = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.btnReset setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.btnReset.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.btnReset.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    [self.btnReset addTarget:self action:@selector(resetView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 150.0;
    self.tableView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-5);
    self.tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    self.tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;


    [self.headerView addSubview:self.lblTitle];
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.btnReset];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableView];

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];

}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.lblTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.btnReset.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"scrollView": self.scrollView,
                 @"headerView": self.headerView,
                 @"lblTitle": self.lblTitle,
                 @"btnReset": self.btnReset,
                 @"imageView": self.imageView,
                 @"tableView": self.tableView
                 };

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[scrollView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];



    self.scrollViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.scrollViewTopConstraint];




    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[headerView(320)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView(320)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-150-[tableView(300)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView(320)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView(320)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lblTitle]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lblTitle]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnReset(80)]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[btnReset]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Methods -

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - ScrollView Delegate -

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //NSLog(@"scrollView offset = %lf", scrollView.contentOffset.y);

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -145)
    {
        //self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        self.scrollViewTopConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

            [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}

-(void)resetView
{
    self.scrollViewTopConstraint.constant = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

What you get when you open the app:

[image: screenshot 1]

Then you drag down to the edge, the view snaps open:

[image: screenshot 2]

Press the red reset button to bring it back up :D

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer :) I've already tried it and it works fine. my problem is that once you hit a certain contentOffset the table view will go outside the screen. what I really want to achieve is the tableview (and the navigation bar) to follow my finger (it should start animating only when release and passed a certain contentOffset). you can see that in the first animation from the video

Comment: What's stopping you from performing the check to trigger the table slide down in the other `scrollViewDidEndDragging` delegate method instead of the `scrollViewDidScroll` method ? I only did it in the scrollViewDidScroll method as a quick hack.

Comment: I'm wondering how this can be done with custom view controller transition. it might be cleaner and it can be used later on once you have the boiler plate code is written. what would be the best practice for that?